# What is the difference between setTimeout(() => btn.click()) and btn.click() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, click, transform, settimeout

Below find my code,

```
#box {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}

<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
    const box = document.getElementById('box');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      box.style.transform = 'translateX(1000px)';
      box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-in-out';

      getComputedStyle(box).transform;
      box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
      
    });

    // method 1
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
    
    // method 2
    setTimeout(() => {
      btn.click();
    }, 1000)
    
</script>
```

> Google Chrome: Version 92.0.4515.107（Official Version)(x86_64)

> Firefox: Version: 90.0.2

This is my first question in StackOverflow.
in the above code, method 1 and method 2 will lead to different animations, why is that?

**Update:**
I'm not talking about 1-second delays

Online example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-tharp-ommki?file=/index.html

and then change code and take a look
look at these gifs:

[method1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK0yn.gif)

[method2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jrDE.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Tried it myself and it appears that it's the same animation but with 1 second delay, no other differences.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-tharp-ommki?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is used to delay the task and then execute it where as a direct btn.click() won't delay the task.

for example.

```js
function a() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("hello"), 1000);
  console.log("world");
}

a()
```

will print world first & then print hello after 1 sec.

Comment: I may not have described the problem clearly. Look at the update of the problem

Answer (score 0):

btn.click() function evaluates instantly whereas if you use setTimeOut() function, the evaluation is done after a specified number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Note that, 1000 ms = 1 second.

Comment: I may not have described the problem clearly. Look at the update of the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use `btn.onclick()`, the code runs as soon as you click the button. What `setTimeout()` does is that it delays the function, so if you have something like

```js
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Delay for 5 seconds');
        }, 5000);
    }
```

```html
    <button>Click me</button>
```

Then it is going to console log whatever I've written after a five second delay.

Comment: I may not have described the problem clearly. Look at the update of the problem